# Change the content type to image/png - cakephp

Tags: image, cakephp, content-type

I have a cakephp application .I understand that my app uses a default.ctp for its layout .In default layout my header is set to html/text .I want to change my header type to image/png .Where should i change it ? Pls someone help me

Code:

```
$this->layout=NULL; 
$this->autoRender=false; 
$this->RequestHandler->respondAs('image/jpg');

      View Coding :(index.ctp)
           <?php 
           session_start(); 
           $text = rand(10000,99999); 
           $_SESSION["vercode"] = $text; 
           $height = 25; 
           $width = 65; 

           $image_p = imagecreate($width, $height); 
           $black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0); 
            $white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255); 
            $font_size = 14; 
            imagestring($image_p, $font_size, 5, 5, $text, $white); 
            imagejpeg($image_p, null, 80); 
                  ?>
           Controller coding :

                public function index() 
                {
                      $this->layout=false;
                      $this->response->type('png');
                }
```

Note: CakePHP version 2.3.0

Comment: where is your code ? what have you tried ?

Comment: why did you not specify your cakephp version?

Comment: So, you are saying your layout only consists of raw PNG data?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor $this->layout=NULL;
   $this->autoRender=false;
   $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('image/jpg'); I have tried this code but its nor working .

Comment: @mark version 2.3.0 is cakephp version

Comment: @Oldskool ya i need to display an image my layout .I should i edit my default.ctp ?or we can make our default layout null and have my new layout with my new content header?

Comment: also don't use session_start() stuff, use `$this->Session->read()` to access your session data!

Comment: @mark Thanks alot sir .I got the output changing to session_start()  $this->Session->read().Thanks so much :)

Comment: OK, so you are creating a JPEG with `imagejpeg()`, which is not PNG. Try `image/jpeg` content-type instead.

Comment: very good point @Oldskool. this can explain why the image is rendered invalid by the browser. if you create invalid images in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must return the content of your view/layout as image (which I highly doubt):

```
$this->response->type('png'); // as documented in the 2.x docs
```

will automatically set `image/png` as response type for the header.

If you need to render your view without layout try

```
$this->layout = false;
// OR
$this->render('my_view', false); // false should not render a layout
```

You cannot use "null" as it renders the default layout.

Either way, never call header() stuff in your view, always in your controller via response object.

Comment: thanks Sir ..what i need is i have to display an image but my default.ctp has header type as text/html ..So my image is not getting displayed instead am getting as ���S�M�����S�M��{ so symbols because my conytent type is html .So how should i change my default.ctp 's content header to image/png .

Comment: i tried your code sir this->response->type('png'); .but am getting error stating "The image cannot be dispalyed as it contains errors"

Comment: because your layout/view is not an image right? it is still html... you should post your layout and view code in your question, as well.

Comment: sorry sir.I have posted my coding .I have only my default.ctp layout .I dint no to create my layout .T thought of disabling my default layout and use response to set my new content type.So my view can display an image

Comment: Thanks sir .I removed my header() call from my view.In my controller i have added $this->layout=false;
             $this->response->type('png'); .But am still getiing an error "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

Comment: i have included my controller coding .please casn you direct me in displaying the image

Answer (score 2):

### Using CakePHP 3

You should always try to do it the CakePHP way instead of setting the headers manually by using PHP's header() function. In this case, the documentation was not very clear. I had to figure it out.

This is how I made it work using CakePHP 3.3:

- First, get the contents of the image into a variable, because we want CakePHP to render that content, not just output and die.
- Then destroy the image resource to free memory.
- **Optional:** you may set cache headers. (commented in the code below)
- Set response object type to "jpg" or "png", etc. [See docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#dealing-with-content-types)
- Set the layout to: "*false*"
- Output the image to the response body and set autoRender to false to avoid creating an unnecessary template file (.ctp).

```php
// Controller method
public function image($id = null) {
    // Create an image resource: $image ...
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($image);
    $buffer = ob_get_clean();
    imagedestroy($image);

    // $this->response->cache('-1 minute', '+1 days');
    $this->response->type('jpg');
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout(false);
    $this->response->body($buffer);
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

Comment: Best answer. Is there a way to send image to buffer from gd library without using ob_start() / $buffer = ob_get_clean() ? - seams not elegant.

Comment: Looks good, however according to [request-response.html#sending-a-string-as-file](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-a-string-as-file), all the `autoRender` trickery is unnecessary if one just returns the response instead, in order to stop the controller from trying to render

Answer (score -1):

(Yeah, old thread, but I just came across this problem.)

```
$this->autoRender = false;
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

in a Controller's method worked for me.